# EXSLT node-set stripping out attributes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, exslt

I've noticed this before but can't remember how I got round it. EXSLT seems to be stripping out attributes when node-setting a string of XML.

Here's a contrived example (I have stripped out the XSLT stylesheet tag for brevity, but EXSLT's common library is being loaded, into the namespace `exsl`).

**XML**

```
<xml>
    <node />
    <node />
    <node />
</xml>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name='nodeset' select='exsl:node-set(xml/node)' />
    <xsl:copy-of select='$nodeset' />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='node'><node foo='bar' /></xsl:template>
```

**Result**

```
<node/><node/><node/>
```

[Demo Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/gdCWpX) (see output **source**)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `exsl:node-set` on nodes in the input XML. You only need to use it if you construct a result tree fragment in a variable and then want to use XPath to select nodes in the result tree fragment.

As for the sample input, none of the `node` elements has any attributes. And the template matching `node` is never applied as your template matching the document node simply creates a variable selecting `xml/node` elements in the input and then outputs a copy of them to the result tree.

Comment: Silly me. It had been a long day. I had clearly meant to apply the templates - in my actual code, I do, but in this demo I spectacularly managed to avoid this crucial line. I think my brain had packed up for the evening. I'm well aware of the need cases for node-sets, it's just I was making a very silly oversight. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need `exsl:node-set` for your sample, doing `<xsl:variable name="result-tree-fragment"><xsl:apply-templates select="xml/node"/></xsl:variable>` would work fine. And as long as you only want to copy that result tree fragment with `<xsl:copy-of select="$result-tree-fragment"/>` you don't need the `exsl:node-set` function either. It is only necessary to select nodes in the result tree fragment e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($result-tree-fragment)/node/@foo"/>`.

Comment: Thanks again - didn't know about result-tree-fragment.

Answer (score -1):

One other point to add to Martin Honnen's response: EXSLT is a specification, not an implementation. If there is a bug, it is in the implementation, not the spec. So we would need to know what implementation you are using.

However, you have provided no evidence of a bug. You appear to be confused as to what exslt:node-set() is intended to do.